# What is the correct order to install SharePoint 2010 SP2 on Three Tier Farm?

Tags: 2010, service-pack-2

Hi We are installing SharePoint 2010 SP2 directly on Windows Server 2012. We have two WFE, one APP and 1 SQL server. Can someone confirm if the installation order to be WFE 1, WFE 2 and APP 1 is the correct approach ? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of installation does not matter. But generally one starts with the server where Central Administration will reside, which is most often the "app" server.